# Splitting data to training and testing

Tags: split, scikit-learn, training-data

Does anyone know how can I train on one dataset and test on another dataset?
So far I only know we can split one dataset into training and testing with this line of code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
        train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=1)
```

I don't know what part I should change in that line if we train on one dataset and test on another dataset.

Comment: The other dataset must have same number and types of features for this to happen. Other than that, just train the model with first dataset, and predict on other. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The line on code you provided about [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) is the first step into training and testing on different parts of your Dataset. After that you will need to `fit` a `model` and `predict` some given outcome given that `model`.

However, it seems that you're new to machine learning and scikit-learn and simply answering your question wouldn't really help you out, instead I'm gonna recommend that you follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elojMnjn4kk&index=1&list=PL5-da3qGB5ICeMbQuqbbCOQWcS6OYBr5A), it's pretty simple and clear and also straightforward.

This will help you get started and give you a good understanding on how training and testing work, and give you some example about `cross_validation`.

Just in case, here is another [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html) you could follow for better understanding. this one is a little bit more complexe so check it in second place.

After these, you will be pretty much able to find your way using scikit-learn official documentation.

EDIT:

If you want to work on completely different sets, it's almost the same as `train_test_split`, the only difference now is that you won't be splitting your data to train and test parts with:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
        train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=1)
```

instead you will just take your first data_set ( the one for training) and make your `X_train` and `y_train` out of it:

```
X_train = data_train[feature_cols]
y_train = data_train['y_col']
```

and the same for your testing set (provided you have one):

```
X_test = data_test[feature_cols] # make sure you're having the same features
y_test = data_test['y_col']
```

After that, nothing really changes.

Now, if you noticed, it's the exact same case of using `train_test_split` if you had the two datasets combined (with the exception that `train_test_split` divides the data randomly)

I believe this is what you asked for.

Hope this was somehow helpful.

Comment: I am familiar with machine learning and all the concept you mentioned! what i haven't seen yet is training in a whole dataset and testing in a completely new dataset!

Comment: @user8034918 You keep saying "a whole new dataset". What do you exactly mean by that? Do the type and number of features differ between the two dataset? If yes, then you may not use that for testing. Because it doesn't make any sense. Machine learning can only do so much.

Comment: No I think he means same features but just new samples @VivekKumar, and so do I btw